# how to send a list of derived types over API (WCF) .NET

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a service method which returns a `List<BaseClass>` but sometimes I might send a `DerivedClass : BaseClass` in the list.

The issue is I want to send the information through. So far I have:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass {
    string Data { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[DataContract(Name="BaseClass")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    string MoreData { get; set; }
}
```

But when the client recieves the data, it's all as a type `BaseClass`.

Comment: Are you using DataContract serialization or XmlSerialization? Show your type definitions. Derived types can be handled as long as your contract is defined correctly and serializer is aware of it.

Comment: @loopedcode updated question, sorry I've managed to solve the exception, but missing data.

Comment: Try to add attribute to base class: `[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]`

Comment: @Roma and remove (Name="BaseClass") from derived?

Comment: @captainjamie, set another name: `"DerivedType"` or another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `KnownType` attribute to `BaseClass` and change `Name` for `DerivedClass` or remove it:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass 
{
    string Data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="DerivedType")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{
    string MoreData { get; set; }
}
```

[KnownTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I just removed the (Name="DerivedType") an everything worked fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Following should fix your issue:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass {
    string Data { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```